# Writing Python output as xlsx

Tags: python, bioinformatics, xlsxwriter, biopython

I want to execute same function (gives output A, B, C, D) for all the files (library) available in the given path. I am trying write the output (A,B,C,D) in four different columns of a sheet in xlsx. Also, the sheet name of xlsx should be same as the respected file available in the path.

I have written the following code:

```
def create_xlsx_file(xlsx_name, file_path): 
    
    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(xlsx_name) ### creates a xlsx file
    workbook.close()
    libraries=os.listdir(file_path)
    
    file_path=os.chdir(file_path)
    for library in libraries: ### to create the sheets named same as the library 
        # print(library)
        if library.endswith('.txt'):
            # library=file_path+library
            # print(library)
            main(library, xlsx_name) 

def main(library, xlsx_name): ###library = all files in the given path
    directory=os.chdir(os.getcwd())
    workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(xlsx_name)
    worksheet = workbook.create_sheet(library, 0)##### creates workshhets named same as library name
    #print('library is: - ',library)
    sheet=workbook[library] ###to create column headers
    sheet.cell(column=1, row=1, value='value_A')
    sheet.cell(column=2, row=1, value='value_B')
    sheet.cell(column=3, row=1, value='value_C')
    sheet.cell(column=4, row=1, value='value_D')
    workbook.save(xlsx_name)
    with open(library, 'r') as library:
        for line in library:

            A=line.split(' ')[0]
            B=line.split(' ')[1]
            C=line.split(' ')[2]
            D=line.split(' ')[3]

            sheet=workbook[library]
            sheet.cell(column=1, row=sheet.max_row+1, value=str(A))
            sheet.cell(column=2, row=sheet.max_row, value=str(B))
            sheet.cell(column=3, row=sheet.max_row, value=str(C))
            sheet.cell(column=4, row=sheet.max_row, value=str(D))
            
    print(f'library  {library} has been written at {os.getcwd()}')
    #time.sleep(1)
    workbook.save(xlsx_name)
```

This code works absolutely fine for me but it is too slow to write xlsx file as my path has hundreds of .txt libraries and each library have more than millions of lines.

I could save the output(A,B,C,D) as .txt format and then can write xlsx file manually but it is very laboursome.

Is there any way to fasten this process? or any other fast xlsx writer is available?
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a faster way to save my data into excel is :
Since I have output as a result of a for loop, first save the output(A,B,C,D) into a dictionary and then save into excel using pandas.

```
def create_xlsx_file(xlsx_name, file_path):

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(xlsx_name) ### creates a xlsx file
workbook.close()
libraries=os.listdir(file_path)

file_path=os.chdir(file_path)
for library in libraries: ### to create the sheets named same as the library 
    # print(library)
    if library.endswith('.txt'):
        # library=file_path+library
        # print(library)
        main(library, xlsx_name) 

def main(library, xlsx_name): ###library = all files in the given path
    dic={'label_A':[], 'label_B':[],'label_C':[],'label_D':[]}# to store A,B,C,D values.
    directory=os.chdir(os.getcwd())
    workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(xlsx_name)
    worksheet = workbook.create_sheet(library, 0)##### creates workshhets named same as library name
    #print('library is: - ',library)
    sheet=workbook[library] ###to create column headers
    sheet.cell(column=1, row=1, value='value_A')
    sheet.cell(column=2, row=1, value='value_B')
    sheet.cell(column=3, row=1, value='value_C')
    sheet.cell(column=4, row=1, value='value_D')
    workbook.save(xlsx_name)
    with open(library, 'r') as library:
       for line in library:

        A=line.split(' ')[0]
        B=line.split(' ')[1]
        C=line.split(' ')[2]
        D=line.split(' ')[3]

        dic['label_A'].append(A)
        dic['label_B'].append(B)
        dic['label_C'].append(C)
        dic['label_D'].append(D)
        
    df=pd.DataFrame(data=dic, columns=['label_A', 'label_B', 'label_C', 'label_D'])
    df.to_excel(xlsx_name, sheet_name=library)
    print(f'library  {library} has been written at {os.getcwd()}')
    #time.sleep(1)
    workbook.save(xlsx_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if i understand correctly, you have a TXT file in which each line has only 4 words.

> That is why you are doing:

```
A=line.split(' ')[0]  
B=line.split(' ')[1]  
C=line.split(' ')[2]  
D=line.split(' ')[3]
```

And if this is TRUE, you can just reach each TXT file as a data-frame and use the column/row splitting technique and assign the values to the columns.

[image: Something like this]

And then you can save the result as required in the CSV.
This way is much faster than normally looping. And even if you have uneven number of words in a line, you can still use this method and subset the first 4 columns only and that should also solve your problem.

Comment: Actually my text file has lines with many breaks (spaces) and function is to find the content before and after the space. To make it easy to understand I wrote A=line.split(' ')[0]

Comment: Pandas is smart enough to do that, the **sep** argument is for that purpose only. For each line, it will take one word as one column value and will keep iterating until all the rows/lines in your txt file are exhausted.

Answer (score 0):

in my experience pandas library is pretty fast to handle information and has a function to export data with xlsx format.
You could create an empty `DataFrame`

`data = pd.DataFrame()`

Save your rows in `pd.Series`. For example:

`row = pd.Series(data=[A,B,C,D], index =  ['value_A', 'value_B', 'value_C', 'value_D'])`

index parameter are the names of your columns and data parameter the values on each row.

Add each row to the `DataFrame`

`data = data.append(row, ignore_index = True)`

And just export DataFrame to xlsx

`data.to_excel("output.xlsx")`

references
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html

Don't forget install pandas library and import it to your program
`import pandas as pd`

I hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

From your code it seems that you don't need any formatting or function of xlsx, and if you only need to centralize your data, a simple csv will do with only tiny changes on your code

```
import csv

def create_xlsx_file(xlsx_name, file_path): 
    
    with open(xlsx_name, 'w', encoding='UTF8') as output_file:
        writer = csv.writer(output_file)
        writer.writerow(['value_A','value_B','value_C','value_D'])
    
    libraries=os.listdir(file_path)
    
    for library in libraries: ### to create the sheets named same as the library 
        # print(library)
        if library.endswith('.txt'):
            # library=file_path+library
            # print(library)
            main(library, xlsx_name) 

def main(library, xlsx_name)
    with open(xlsx_name, 'a', encoding='UTF8') as output_file:
        writer = csv.writer(output_file)
        with open(library, 'r', encoding='UTF8') as input_file:
            lines = input_file.read().splitlines()
            for line in lines:
                A=line.split(' ')[0]
                B=line.split(' ')[1]
                C=line.split(' ')[2]
                D=line.split(' ')[3]
                writer.writerow([A,B,C,D])
                print(f'library  {library} has been written at {os.getcwd()}')
```